# Importing a List from an independent file

Tags: list, haskell, import, module

following problem: I'm trying to import a Haskell file which includes a List as a module.
My header looks the following:

```
module Actualfile where
import Filewithlist
```

The error message:  parse error on input ‘module’ . Both files are in the same folder.
The Filewithlist file only contains a List, does it also needs sth like a header?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

Module names need to be capitalized.

Comment: sry I did. I failed in generalizing the names.

Comment: @SiXa- are you still getting the same error with the capitalization?  It works for me now....